# Django custom model - field username gets removed

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am writing a custom user model using django and I have username field along with email field. When I set `USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'`, I get this error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: User has no field named 'username'`

When I checked the migrations for the model, I found that the username field did not exist among the model fields.

I tried flushing and making migrations again, but it still the same,
but when I changed the field name to something other than username it works.

Here is my model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from django.db.models.enums import Choices
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
    
    
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password, full_name = None, role='USER'):
        if not (email and username and password) :
            raise ValueError ("Missing Data (username, email, password).")
        user_object = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user_object.username = username
        if full_name:
            user_object.full_name = full_name
        user_object.set_password(password)
        user_object.role = role
        user_object.save(using=self._db)
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, full_name=None,):
        self.create_user(
            username= username,
            email=email,
            full_name= full_name,
            password = password,
            role= 'ADMIN'
        )
    
    def create_staff(self, username, email, password, full_name=None,):
        self.create_user(
            username= username,
            email=email,
            full_name= full_name,
            password = password,
            role= 'STAFF'
        )
    
    
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        
    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        User = 'USER', _('User')
        Admin = 'ADMIN', _('Admin')
        Staff = 'STAFF', _('Staff')
    
    username        = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    email           = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique= True, verbose_name="Email")
    full_name       = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name="Full Name", null=True, blank=True)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Active")
    role            = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Role.choices, default=Role.User, verbose_name="Role")
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    objects = UserManager
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['username', 'email','password']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
        
    @property
    def role(self):
        return self.role
    
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return (self.role == self.Role.Admin)
    
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return (self.role == self.Role.Staff)
    
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
    
    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually got it to work by removing :

```
@property
def username(self):
    return self.username
```

but i am not sure about the reason
maybe becasue i used the property decorator

i would like to know the reason

Comment: Well, you replaced the field with a property by doing that. The field doesn't exist if you do that. As an aside, accessing that property would lead into infinite recursion.

Comment: makes sense now thanks